# how to get data(user details) from one table to another when the user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql

How do i get details from a table to another table when a user is logged in. The details include their names (first, last), email and uid. The table that I want to fetch data is from the data entered when the user was registering. So does my code make any sense or is there any other way to achieve what I'm asking for? I have also attached pictures. 
My purpose for this is to know which user entered the amount (bidamount)
Data comes from:
[image: where the data is coming from]
Data goes to:
[image: where data is to be entered]

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {

    $bidamount = $_POST['bidamount'];
    $ratings   = $_POST['ratings'];


    //TO ALERT SUBMISSION OF BLANK FIELDS(IT DOESN'T PREVENT SUBMISSION OF BLANK FIELD THOUGH)
    if (!$bidamount) {
        echo "can't submit blank fields";
    }

    //TO CONFIRM YOU ARE CONNECTED TO YOUR DATABASE (OPTIONAL)
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'tickmill_auctions');
    if ($connection) {
        echo "we are connected";
    } else {
        die("connection failed");
    }

    // TO INSERT USER DETAILS IN THE TABLE
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
        $uid         = $_SESSION['u_uid'];
        $query       = "SELECT * FROM tickmill_auctions WHERE user = '$uid'";
        $result      = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `son_of_man`
                                (`first`,
                                `last`,
                                `uid`,
                                `email`)
                         SELECT `first`,
                                 `last`,
                                 `uid`,
                                 `email`
                            FROM `tickmill_auctions`
                           WHERE `user` = '$uid'");
        }
    }
    //TO INSERT username and password from field to jossyusers database
    $query  = "INSERT INTO son_of_man(bidamount, ratings) VALUES('$bidamount','$ratings')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("OOPPS! query failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: your code is so vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: Please read this before asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif thank you for pointing it out. I am actually doing this for my class project. It's not really a concern right now since it's in my localhost

Comment: @EthanDennis : SQL Injection is always a concern, and in class is the best time to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to add the full user detail in another table, read [Normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) in SQL, just used the id of the user as foreign id to store the data in bid table. And then when you show the result on front view, you can use the JOINS to get the data from 2 tables.

And morevoer in query `SELECT * FROM tickmill_auctions WHERE user = '$uid'`, there is no user `field` in any table.